# JavaScript function to multiply by two each element of an array

Tags: javascript

I want someone to review my code and tell me what I did wrong. I want a function that receives an array of numbers as a parameter and returns a new array with each element multiplied by two.

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  let numDouble = arr;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
      Total = numDouble * 2;
    }
  }
  return numDouble;
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(duplicate(arr))
```

Comment: Do you want it to affect the original array, or make a new array based on the old one?

Answer (score 2):

## Debug

Your solution was not working because you weren't assigning the new value into the array

It will works if you use the following code to do this :

```js
numDouble[i] = numDouble[i] * 2;
```

By the way, there is no need to check if the value is `0` because 0 * 2 still equal 0 which works perfectly. so you could have removed the `if(arr[i]!=0)` part.

Also, when you're doing `let numDouble = arr;` you aren't creating a new array but assigning the existing array reference into the variable.

If you want to create a new array you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which is used for example to duplicates array.

Example : `let numDouble = [...arr];`

You would have checked if there was a **division** that might cause a problem

Example :

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  let numDouble = [...arr];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    numDouble[i] = numDouble[i] * 2;
  }
  return numDouble;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const newArr = duplicate(arr)

console.log(newArr)
```

---

## Another solution

Another solution that might works better is the `map` function which take a function an apply it to every item of the array

So for example you could do this :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const multiplyByTwo = function(number) {
  return number * 2
}

console.log(arr.map(multiplyByTwo))
```

Or even with one line of code using arrow functions :

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]

console.log(arr.map(x => x*2))
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are a couple of errors in your code, outlined below:**

---

`let numDouble = arr;`

This does not create a new array. Instead it creates a new reference to the same array. This means that when you modify `numDouble` you're also modifying `arr`

---

`if(arr[i]!=0)`

I am not sure what your trying to do with this condition, but it is unnecessary as 2* 0 = 0 anyway. Unless you want to exclude 0 value from the final array ?

---

`Total = numDouble * 2;`

The variable `Total` is not defined. Also in javascript the convention is to use [camelCase](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/CamelCase#:%7E:text=CamelCase%20is%20a%20naming%20convention,name%20can%20easily%20be%20read.) for variable names.

Furthermore `numDouble` is an array here, you can't use the multiplication operator. `numDouble * 2` evaluates to [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

---

**Possible implementation**

A possible implementation for your function would be:

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  const doubleNum = []

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    doubleNum.push(2 * arr[i])
  }
  return doubleNum
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(duplicate(arr))
```

Although in real life, we would simply use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so :

`const numDouble = arr.map(i => 2*i)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=[2,1,5];
   
function duplicate(arr){
  var Total=[];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]!=0){
      Total.push(arr[i] * 2);      
      
    } 
  } 
  console.log(Total)
  return Total;
}
duplicate(a);
```

you can use the push() method . it adds one or more elements to the end of an array

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change this one line of code:

```
function duplicate(arr) {
    let numDouble = arr;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != 0) {
            // Total = numDouble * 2;
            numDouble[i] = numDouble[i] * 2;
        }
    }
    return numDouble;
}
```

Also you don't have to check if value is not equal to 0.

Comment: There is no need to check for `arr[i]` being `!= 0` :)

Comment: function duplicate(arr){
  let numDouble = arr;
  for(let i=0; i=arr.length; i++){
    if(arr!=0){
      numDouble[i]= numDouble[i] * 2; 
    }
  }
  return numDouble;
}
console.log(duplicate([1,2,3,4,5]));                                                            when I enter an array as a parameter with this code it does not duplicate the numbers

Comment: @Tvde1 Yeah, I wrote about it at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

when I enter an array as a parameter with this code it does not duplicate the numbers

```
function duplicate(arr){
  let numDouble = arr;
  for(let i=0; i=arr.length; i++){
    if(arr!=0){
      numDouble[i]= numDouble[i] * 2; 
    }
  }
  return numDouble;
}
console.log(duplicate([1,2,3,4,5]));
```